# How to open and work with dbf files in php

Tags: php, dbf

My php version in 5.1.6 and I do not have admin privileges.

I want to open a `.dbf` file with a `.php` script. I tried `dbase_open()` which did not work.

Any other option is there?

Comment: First I recommend to upgrade your PHP version before doing anything else.

Comment: @Daan Yep. PHP 5.1.6 is nearly ten years old, and is likely to be affected by dozens of major security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Do you have a proper PHP extension installed? You can check with `phpinfo()` function, or in console with `php -m`.